# Xpath in Javascript, not working?

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath

I am tryin to write a class that selects the dom elemented, by using XPath.
So far, this is my code.
Problem is, node.id, makes the javascript fail.

What am I doing wrong? :/

```
var evaluator = new XPathEvaluator();

var result = evaluator.evaluate("//div", document.documentElement, null,
                             XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);                 

if (result) {
    alert(result)
    var node = result.iterateNext();
    while(node) {
            alert(node.id);
        node = node.iterateNext();
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be easier to use jQuery and CSS selectors.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. [Meet jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: Since when is easier a good enough argument to skip development? :)
Anyway, I normally do use jQuery, I am just intrested in XPath at the moment and wanted to create a test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result.iterateNext`, not `node.iterateNext`. Type in `$x` into Chrome/Safari Javascript Console for a full example.